Why do we use symbol ";" in extended decimal notation for hyperreal numbers?
There is extended decimal notation for hyperreal numbers which was developed by A.H. Lightstone:
$d.d_1d_2d_3...;...d_{H-1}d_{H}d_{H+1}...$
Why do we use symbol ";" in this notation?
Thanks.

If you mean something like $0.\bar 12$ , so infinite many ones followed by a $2$ this makes no sense , not even as a hyperreal number.

You can use any symbol, $&$, $\wp$, $#$, or even a space. What exactly are you asking? The necessity of a symbol? Or why in particular the semicolon is chosen?

@Trebor The necessity of a symbol.

@Peter, it can be made sense of in the hyperreals (in a certain sense). Wikipedia's notation with $H$ is clearer than OP's notation with $\infty$, but basically if $H$ is a hypernatural number then "$0.$($H$-many ones followed by a two)" does make sense. The semicolon notation is more helpful as it reminds you that the choice of $H$ matters, and that the sequence of ones has a weird order-type (for example, just "$\Bbb N$-many ones" wouldn't make sense).

@IzaakvanDongen Thx for your remark. I edited post.

This is the same problem as with $1+2+3+\cdots=-1/12$. Of course hyperreals make sense  , but not the notation. Nothing can come after infinite many digits.

@Peter: You might be interested in the topic of ordinal numbers. For example, the ordered set of real numbers $\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3},\frac{3}{4},\ldots,\frac{n}{n+1},\ldots;1$ consists of an infinite sequence, followed by the single element $1$. This ordered set represents an ordinal number written in shorthand as $\omega+1$.

If $H$ is an infinite hyperinteger, in Lightstone's notation from

Lightstone, A. H.  Infinitesimals.  Amer. Math. Monthly 79 (1972), 242–251

the number $10^H$ would appear as
$$0.000\ldots;\ldots01$$
where $1$ appears at rank $H$.
The notation ";" separates between the digits at finite ranks from the digits at infinite ranks.
Here a comma cannot be used because it has a different meaning in the context of decimals.  The same goes for a period.  One could use a slash "/" or perhaps a vertical bar, but ";" is better because it suggests a pause rather than a full stop, since the decimal digits continue beyond the standard ranks.
